# Get device screen height in React Native when Full Screen Gesture feature is enabled and the device have a Notch

Tags: android, react-native, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

I need to get the real screen **height** of devices that have enabled the ***Full Screen Gesture*** feature and ***have a notch***.

The thing is that both of this device features can be modified by users, I mean enabling/disabling Full Screen Gesture and enabling the notch hiding.

I've tried using functions of **"Dimensions"** class of React Native without results.

**How can I detect if these features are enabled on the current device to properly adapt the height of the screen?**

[image: Example of Full Screen Gesture in Xiamomi Redmi 7]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing a little with CSS in RN, I found that when using Flex model, some properties may be so tricky.

In my case, the real problem was to **expand a view to the device height**, no matter if the device have notch or the gesture mode enabled.

If we set **`flex: 1`** to every hierarchical level of views, from root parent to the desired view, then that views will **behave as full height/width**.

Example:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}">
    <View style={{flex: 1}}">
        <View style={{flex: 1}}">
            This view will expand to full height and width
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```